# Equality between StringOps and WrappedString instances

Tags: scala

I'm just learning Scala so I apologize if this has already been discussed but the following seemed a bit odd to me:

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable._
import scala.collection.immutable._

scala> val st1 = new WrappedString("Hello")
st1: scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString = Hello

scala> val st2 = new StringOps("Hello")
st2: scala.collection.immutable.StringOps = Hello

scala> st2 == st1
res0: Boolean = true

scala> st1 == st2
res1: Boolean = false
```

Can anyone explain this?  I am using Scala version 2.10.0-M4.  I haven't tried this with
anything other versions.

Comment: Same behavior on scala 2.9.1.final for what it's worth.

Comment: @Brian It seems that scala 2.9.2(Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.7.0_02)  behaves differently in my computer.

Comment: Same behaviour with scala 2.9.2 and java build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-10M3527

Answer (score 7):

The reason why there occur differences is documented in ScalaDoc.

WrappedString:

> The difference between this class and `StringOps` is that calling
>   transformer methods such as `filter` and `map` will yield an object of
>   type `WrappedString` rather than a `String`.

StringOps:

> The difference between this class and `WrappedString` is that calling
>   transformer methods such as `filter` and `map` will yield a `String`
>   object, whereas a `WrappedString` will remain a `WrappedString`.

Both derive from `collection.GenSeqLike` which defines an equals method:

```
override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
  case that: GenSeq[_] => (that canEqual this) && (this sameElements that)
  case _ => false
}
```

Both implement the `canEqual` (derived from `collection.IterableLike`) which [returns always true](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0-M4/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L292). But `StringOps` is not a `collection.GenIterable`:

```
scala> st1 sameElements st2
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.StringOps
 required: scala.collection.GenIterable[?]
              st1 sameElements st2
                               ^
```

Whereas `WrappedString` does:

```
scala> st2 sameElements st1
res13: Boolean = true
```

So it should obvious why the first case returns `true` and the other one `false`.

But why do both exist? I'm not totally sure why it is designed this way, but I think that's because of the fact that a String is not a collection in Scala. When we do some operation on a String like `"abc" flatMap (_+"z")` we wanna get back another String even though it is not always possible as shown by `"abc" map (_+1)`. This is what `StringOps` does. But when we have some method `def x[A](s: Seq[A]) = s.getClass` how shall we call it with a String? In this case we need `WrappedString`:

```
scala> x("a")
res9: Class[_ <: Seq[Char]] = class scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString
```

So, `StringOps` is more lightweight as `WrappedString`. It allows us to call some methods on plain old `java.lang.String` without doing too much overhead. In 2.10 `StringOps` extend `AnyVal`. This means it is a value class and its existence can be optimized by scalac (no runtime overhead any more by wrapping the String). In contrast `WrappedString` allows us to handle a String as a real collection - as an `IndexedSeq[Char]`.

Comment: "But why do both exist? ... because of the fact that a String is not a collection in Scala." Pretty much.  The motivation can most easily be seen in the desire to have "bob" == "bob".reverse be true.  We can't influence String's equals method, so sensible behavior depends on collections methods returning another String when it makes sense.  It is unavoidable that sometimes you need a collection of chars and sometimes you need a String.  And implicits can't save you, because ==/equals take an "Any" argument, which will never implicitly convert.